# How to show my app and browser launched as an intent in the recent apps list?

Tags: android, browser, android-intent

In my application, I want to launch a web browser to display some web content. Since the content is long enough, I want to let user switch between my app and the browser using home long press (recent apps). I tried calling the url like-

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

It works fine on Nexus S, where I can see both the browser and my app in the recent apps so that user can switch between them. But on some other devices (I tried on HTC Wildfire S too) it does not show browser in the recent apps list.

So can we somehow make the browser and the app show in the recent apps list? One way is to start browser as an application programmatically, but then the next problem is how to load a specific URL into that browser?

Comment: You should edit your question title, it is somewhat misleading because you give a straight answer to the question as part of your complete question.

Comment: Would an activity with a `WebView` be an alternative?

Comment: No. Because, since it'll be an activity, it will be considered as part of my application only and in the recent apps I will see only my application's icon, so how will I switch between the two?

Comment: Not sure about it, but what happens if you specify the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to your intent via addFlags, as described at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK ? Seems it corresponds to your workflow.

Comment: @SirDarius : That did not work either. Thanks though.

Answer (score -2):

1. Create a URI
   Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://blog.myprotocol.in/");
2. Crate Intent for browser
   Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
3. start the activity
   startActivity(launchBrowser);

Comment: How do you think this varies form what the user has tried and posted here already?

Comment: And moreover, since we are starting an activity, there is not browser icon in the recent apps list since it'll be treated as my application's activity only.